# is_active_sidebar() problem

Tags: theme-development, widgets, deactivation

I'm trying to develop a wordpress theme with a hero slider, I use some 3rd party slider widget inserted to the hero widget area I've defined as ***sidebar-hero*** in my `functions.php` file.

I'm using this code to display the hero slider:

```
<?php if(is_active_sidebar("sidebar-hero")) : ?>
    <?php dynamic_sidebar("sidebar-hero");?>
    <script type="text/javascript">document.body.classList.add("hero-widget-enabled");</script>
<?php else: ?>
<div class="carousel-page-container container">
    <div class="header-filter" style='background-image: url(/wp-content/themes/sometheme/assets/images/demo/back.png)'>
        <div class="header-filter-gradient"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif;?>
```

Now the problem is, I add the custom slider to the sidebar-hero widget area, it shows the slider. I remove the slider from the widgets, it shows the default image. But when I disable the slider from the extensions page without removing it from the widget area, it still tries to show the dynamic sidebar.

The `is_active_sidebar()` method returns `true` even if there are any widgets displayed in the widget settings page on the sidebar-hero widget area.

Do you have any solutions for this issue? Is it a wordpress bug, or am I doing something wrong?

**Update**

`wp_get_sidebars_widgets()` shows this output (which **smartslider3-2** should not 
 be included because it's plugin is disabled):

```
array(6) {
  ["wp_inactive_widgets"]=>
  array(11) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "archives-2"
    [1]=>
    string(10) "archives-4"
    [2]=>
    string(6) "meta-2"
    [3]=>
    string(8) "search-2"
    [4]=>
    string(8) "search-4"
    [5]=>
    string(6) "text-2"
    [6]=>
    string(12) "categories-2"
    [7]=>
    string(14) "recent-posts-2"
    [8]=>
    string(17) "recent-comments-2"
    [9]=>
    string(6) "text-3"
    [10]=>
    string(11) "tag_cloud-2"
  }
  ["sidebar-primary"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(12) "categories-3"
    [1]=>
    string(11) "tag_cloud-1"
    [2]=>
    string(10) "calendar-1"
  }
  ["sidebar-footer-1"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(14) "recent-posts-3"
  }
  ["sidebar-footer-2"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(7) "pages-2"
  }
  ["sidebar-footer-3"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(11) "tag_cloud-3"
  }
  ["sidebar-hero"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(14) "smartslider3-2"
  }
}
```

Comment: Where and how are you calling is_active_widget? Please edit your question and add the relevant code.

Comment: That should be `is_active_sidebar`. Thanks for the heads up. Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

In this case I would simply check if the slider plugin is activated - so your conditional statement would look like this:

```
 <?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-hero' ) && 
            is_plugin_active( 'slider-plugin-dir/slider-plugin-base-file.php' ) 
 ) : ?>
```

`wp_get_sidebars_widgets` in your case works as expected - it checks for the widgets in wp_options table and keeps the widget because it is still there. It makes sense - deactivating the plugin is not the same as removing the widget and this function is not intended to check for widget's dependencies.

Comment: The widget that user added to the sidebar may vary. I don't limit the user to use one type of slider plugin.

Comment: Oh, sorry then, I don't understand entirely what you're trying to achieve. What do you insert into widget then if it's supposed to work with any slider plugin? Any shortcode?

Comment: Nope, any slider plugin such as Revo Slider, Smart Slider, Soliloquy slider can be inserted by the user. Or if he/she doesn't care about the display, he/she could insert any other plugin widget as well. I don't care about what's inserted, but the template enforces user to use a slider widget for the completeness of the theme.